# Django jQuery Rest Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, rest

I have question about `$.getJSON` function in jQuery. The question is, how to name function `$.getJSON` and call it from another function. I mean, when other function do all things, on success call `$.getJSON` function. This is part of Rest Framework, where this function GET result from Rest Framework `url`.

## jQuery

First function for parsing Rest Framework:

```
$.getJSON('/category_1/', function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

        var table = $(".category_product");

        $.each(data, function (index, value) {

//console.log(data);
            var name = value.name;
            var type_id = value.type_id;

            var tr = $("<tr></tr>");
            table.append(tr);

            var td = $("<td>" + name + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);


            var td = $("<td>" + type_id + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);

            var td = $("<td>" + '<img id="nodeGoto1" class="img-responsive;" src="../static/izibizi/images/forms/icon_delete.png">' + "</td>");
            tr.append(td);
        })

        $('#data_table_category_products').dataTable({
                "dom": '<"top"fi>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
                'bLengthChange': false,
                "bFilter": false
            }
        )
        $('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Pretraži Kategorije");
        /*Set custom placeholder to element*/

    });
```

Ok this function works normaly, and all results from REST are parsed to HTML page.

## jQuery

Second function where function is submiting a form, and on succuess it needs to call first function for retrive new results from Rest Framework.

```
$('#category').on('submit', function(){
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/kategorije/",
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        required: true,
        success: function(response) {

            if (!response.success) {
                console.log(response.error.name);
               $.niftyNoty({
                type: 'info',
                container : '#alertajme',
                html : '<h4 class="alert-title">Kategorija sa nazivom <strong>'+response.error.name+'</strong> već postoji!</h4><p class="alert-message">Promjenite naziv kategorije.</p><div class="mar-top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="noty">Zatvorite notifikaciju</button></div>',
                closeBtn : false,
                timer : 5000
            });
            } else {
                $.niftyNoty({
                type: 'info',
                container : '#alertajme',
                html : '<h4 class="alert-title">Kategorija sa nazivom <strong>'+response.success+'</strong> uspješno je kreirana!</h4><div class="mar-top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="noty">Zatvorite notifikaciju</button></div>',
                closeBtn : false,
                timer : 5000
            });

            }
        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
           $.niftyNoty({
                type: 'info',
                container : '#alertajme',
                html : '<h4 class="alert-title">Kategorija sa nazivom <strong>'+"Unesite naziv kategorije."+'</strong></h4><p class="alert-message">Promjenite naziv kategorije.</p><div class="mar-top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="noty">Zatvorite notifikaciju</button></div>',
                closeBtn : false,
                timer : 5000
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

This function must call first function for new results on form submit. The Rest Function is refreshed in #views.py when form is submited. How can this be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So lets say your first function is BLOCK_ONE.
Now you define another function like
`function myGetJSON(){ BLOCK_ONE }`

This way you can call BLOCK_ONE as many times you want.